# Can a website exist without HTML?

Tags: php, html

I previously had someone build a website for me. It was 90% finished but then ill health got in the way.

I have all the files and I am now asking people to "put the website back together for me". The general consensus is that it's very messy and not clear what was done and some of the protocols are now out of date etc. And it would just be better to start from scratch. I have heard this from multiple people.

So now when I am asking a new guy to build it from scratch, he is asking me for the HTML files. I couldn't see any, so I contacted the previous developer and he said:

> There are no HTML files, it all runs through the index.php file and
>   extracts pages, data etc. from the database.

I told this to the new developer, but he is saying:

> But website is not possible without HTML. Ask him provide index HTML. 
>   Pure HTML without php code.

I'm confused, because I saw the website up and running, so it seems it is possible without HTML?

I'm trying to figure out where the misunderstanding is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: your original developer sounds a lot smarter than your new one.

Comment: The php code generates html code, which is then sent to the browser.

Comment: I was trying to figure out who was the weak link!

Comment: it is possible, can you share a link to the site, its possible the html is dynamically generated by the php

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is no longer online. I just have all the files. Getting it online is my goal :)

Comment: many web sites are built like your original one looks to be. the data is in a database and the pages are built with php per request, there need not be any static html files at all. there will be bits of html (template files perhaps) but no 'fully formed html files

Comment: Just because there aren't any HTML files doesn't mean that HTML won't be sent through from the server. It can either be stored in the database as HTML or as something else which PHP will parse and turn into HTML.

Comment: Okay that all answers my question. Thanks everyone.

Comment: your new developer saying that should be a big red-flag; you should not hire him

Comment: Big red flag approved!

Comment: green ticking the red-flag ? @Cryptopat

Comment: If done correctly, a dynamic website is often better than a static website. If your new developer has no understanding of how a dynamic website works you should not be hiring him as there are probably many other things he does not understand that would hinder him from providing you with a good site.

Comment: And like many others have stated here, it should be a pretty sizable red flag that your new developer doesn't know this.  You may want to look elsewhere.  I can't help but sense an impending trainwreck :)

Comment: He's not hired yet, and shan't be after this :) Appreciated.

Comment: this is offtopic on SO by the way, i feel you should delete it, but thats just me

Comment: Has the original developer given you a dump of the database?

Comment: With a bit of luck, a static copy exist into the Internet archive: https://archive.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your previous developer is saying is that your site was dynamic and all requests were flowing through your index.php file, which in turn does some backend logic to produce HTML data for the browser to interpret.  If you ask your previous developer to zip up the root of your old site, your new developer should be able to take it from there.

Comment: ...with a dump of the database :)

Comment: Ha yes, with a database dump.

Answer (score -2):

Can a website exist without HTML?

Without a .html file? Yes. Using only .php, .css and .js is possible. 
Without using Hyper Text Mark-up Language? No. There ar no other mark-up language for browsers, afaik. So we're stuck with this.

Old dev used PHP for efficiency. Contents are in your database and fetched using php to show up in browser.

New dev probably only knows HTML and has no clue about php. Or, probably doesn't want to bother reading through the php codes to reverse engineer how your site works.

Suggestion: Get a different dev. A smarter one. You probably have to pay more, but it's more expensive to hire a less smarter dev.